# Powershell - CSV and Excel Commands

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I am attempting to manipulate a script in powershell to add more variable to a CSV if certain criteria is met. I cant figure it out but I keep getting a popup asking me to select a profile.

```
Write-Output $Trending_Data_To_Output | Out-File $Single_Trending_File -Encoding ASCII -Append
        
        
         If($Comp_Scope -EQ 'CompYes')
            {
            #########################################################################################
            ### Saves Trending File as XLSX and Formats as a Table########################
            $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
            $Excel.Visible = $False
            $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
            $Excel_WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Single_Trending_File)
            
         
            $sheet1 = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item(1)
            $cells1 = $sheet1.cells
            $sheet1.Columns.AutoFit()
            $sheet1.name = "Var 1 Trending"
            $Excel_Workbook.worksheets.add()
            $sheet2 = $Excel_workbook.worksheets.Item(2)
            $sheet2.name = "Var 2 Trending"
            Write-Output $Comp_Column_Labels | Out-File $sheet2 -Encoding ASCII
            Write-Output $Comp_Trending_Data_To_Output | Out-File $sheet2 -Encoding ASCII
            $cells2 = $sheet2.cells
            $sheet2.Columns.AutoFit()
            $ListObject = $excel.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange, $excel.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion, $null ,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlYes)
            $ListObject.Name = "Var 2 Trending"
            $ListObject.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium1"
            Write-Host "Reformatting Comp Data" -foregroundcolor Green
            $xlout=$Single_Trending_File.Replace('.csv','.xlsx') 
            $Excel_WorkBook.SaveAs($xlout,51)

            [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel_WorkBook) | Out-Null
            [System.GC]::Collect()
            [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            Remove-Variable -Name Excel_WorkBook
            $Excel.quit()
            #########################################################################################
            }
```

Comment: If you have input or output as a CSV file, then use the PowerShell CSV commands. `Get-Command -Name '*-csv*'` If you must use Excel files, see the ImportExcel module. `Find-Modue -Name 'ImportExcel'`

Comment: P.S. quit excel **before** you release the COM objects